# How do you connect your terminal with the Android emulator

Tags: android, connection, terminal, emulation

I have tried the navigate to the android tool folder and entering the  "adb shell" command but it doesn't seem to work.  My terminal seems only to recognize the adb part of the command and gives me an error message.  What am I doing wrong???

Comment: I left my crystal ball at home... could you please tell me what error message it gives you?

Comment: Which SO? Linux/Windows?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

1. List all connected devices by typing `adb devices`

Check, if there are any devices listed. If not you may want to check that your device is connected and/or your emulator is running.

2. If it works and you have for example your emulator running and your usb-device connected use:

- `adb shell` if you only have device connected.
- `adb -d shell` to connect to an USB-Device.
- `adb -e shell` to connect to an emulated device.

If you have more than one emulator or usb devices you might want to use:
`adb -s <DEVICE> shell`

**Note**:
Make sure that the path to the android-sdk is properly set-up in your environment. To quickcheck, fire up a shell and type `adb version`. If that command succeeds, you're set up. If not, add `/path/to/android-sdk/tools` and `/path/to/android/platform-tools` to your `$PATH` env variable. On windows the android sdk is typically located in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`.