# How do you change the date of android emulator?

Tags: android

I need to change the date of the emulator how do you do it? I tried the dev settings but they wont let me edit it

Comment: I'm pretty sure, like most things, it gets its time information from your machine.  So, change the time there.  Just make sure your auto-syncing service is turned off (assuming you use one)

Comment: I can change the date of my emulator like on any Android device. I'm using SDK Tools 25.x and API 21 System Image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184863/changing-the-internal-android-simulators-time 
this is duplicate question. please search first and then post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the Internal Android Simulator's Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184863/changing-the-internal-android-simulators-time)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I just tried it. Change it like on any other android device.
Open the normal settings (not the dev) and go to date & time.

Uncheck "Automatic Date & time" and set the desired date below.

[image]

Comment: but is there a way to set a custom time Each time the device boots - (virtually) ?

Answer (score 0):

It gets the time from your host device (the computer you're running the emulator on), so change that and you'll be good to go.

Note that you may need to disable automatic date and time adjustment within the emulator itself, to do that, go into the settings app on the emulator, then "date and time" (near the bottom) and then uncheck the "Use network provided date and time" box.