# How do I mock locations using Health Services on Wear OS?

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os, wearables

I have followed the guide at [Active data and exercises](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services/active#exerciseclient) to set up an exercise client. This works fine on my physical Samsung Galaxy Watch 5 and I get my real-time location.

On emulators inside of Android Studio, however, the location I receive is a constant `longitude 51.530211685534 longitude -0.12388666083292`, which is [in London](https://goo.gl/maps/mkQuUVrdAFSErp8T9).

The way I initialize an exercise client is:

```
healthClient.exerciseClient.setUpdateCallback(excerciseUpdateCallback);

val exerciseConfig = ExerciseConfig(ExerciseType.BIKING, setOf(DataType.LOCATION), false, true);

healthClient.exerciseClient.startExerciseAsync(exerciseConfig);
```

The way I receive location updates is:

```
override fun onExerciseUpdateReceived(update: ExerciseUpdate) {
    println("Recorder: onExerciseUpdate");

    val latestMetrics = update.latestMetrics;
    val locationUpdates = latestMetrics.getData(DataType.LOCATION);
    
    if(locationUpdates.isNotEmpty()) {
        val location = locationUpdates.last();

        println("Last longitude " + location.value.latitude + " longitude " + location.value.longitude);
    }
}
```

The result I always get is:

```
Recorder: onExerciseUpdate
Last longitude 51.530211685534 longitude -0.12388666083292
```

When I start a route, this pops into the console:

```
set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
```

I do not have anything else but the exercise update callback running during this. Only the UI, but nothing is being done nor running in the UI.

I have tried setting a static location point, which has not yielded a change in the coordinates.

I have also tried setting a route, which has also not yielded a change in the coordinates.

This only happens in the emulator, as my physical device is running just fine.

The emulator I am running is the latest one that Android Studio provides me:

> Wear OS Large Round API 30
>
> Android 11.0 Wear OS 3 x86

[[image: Emulator demonstration] Click for a video demonstration](https://imgur.com/a/H1AXYL2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not seen the [Use synthetic data with Health Services](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services/synthetic-data) page.

To enable *synthetic* sensors:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a "whs.USE_SYNTHETIC_PROVIDERS" com.google.android.wearable.healthservices
```

To enable simulated biking location updates:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a "whs.synthetic.user.START_EXERCISE" --ef exercise_options_average_speed 1.2 --ez exercise_options_use_location true com.google.android.wearable.healthservices
```

Related: [How do you connect your terminal with the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784341/how-do-you-connect-your-terminal-with-the-android-emulator)